# OpenIdConnectProtocolException When I Do Not Grant Admin Consent for My API in Azure B2C

Tags: openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C resource and registered my application under App Registrations. If I revoke the admin consent for an API under API Permissions and I test my application I get the error below.

[image]

If I grant the Admin consent everything works fine. Why does an admin consent have to be enabled for an API for it to generate an id_token and an access_token?

Comment: This is because your Web App no more has admin's consent to access API scopes and hence, it cannot access them. This is documented here as well to Grant Admin consent for WebApp to call protected Web API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga#grant-permissions
You can also find the meaning of granting admin consent to each permission, when you click on the permissions.
Let me know if this answers your question, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Hi @HarshitaSingh-MSFT, this seems to be the answer but why doesn't B2C give developers the option to create API scopes that can be granted consent by either an admin or a user? This feature is available in Azure AD.

The premise behind this question is that granting admin consent to an API can be a security concern, is it not?

Comment: If I got your question right, the answer is that admin consent can be given by a user who has Administrator role or at least has Cloud administrator role.

Comment: Apologies if you misunderstood the question. So, in Azure AD if you add a scope there is an option called Who can consent? and you can either select Admins and users or Admins only. If you select the former then you will be able to request for an access token without the need to grant the API admin consent. 

Thus, my question is why this particular option is not available in B2C? Why does all scopes automatically need Admin consent for it to grant authorization to an application?

Answer (score 0):

It is because AAD B2C as a secure token issuer does not support a Oauth 2.0 User consent framework. Therefore, users are not able to consent, and therefore admins must consent prior.

This is similar to Facebook, when you sign up, you agree to their Terms of Service, you don't consent to each and every one of their APIs.

If you would like an OAuth consent type model for your application, then take a look at this sample:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/service-consent